# Two dimensional arrays and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, sub-array

I have the following code snippet:

```
char board[3][3] = {
                     {'1','2','3'},
                     {'4','5','6'},
                     {'7','8','9'}
                   };

printf("address of board : %p\n", &board);
printf("address of board[0] : %p\n", &board[0]);
```

Both `printf()` statements all print the same value: `0x0013ff67`

1. As per my knowledge, board (i.e) array name represents the address of the first subarray (i.e) `board[0]` and
2. `board[0]` represents the address of first element in the first array (i.e) `board[0][0]`

Why am I getting the same address in all my `printf()` statements? I expect different addresses for both statements.

I am pretty new to this stuff and don't understand this behavior. Kindly enlighten me.

Answer (score 5):

Though it's a 2D array, inside the memory it will be represented as linear array. so when you say, board[0][0] it still points to the first element in that linear array and hence the same memory address.

Answer (score 1):

> As per my knowledge, board (i.e) array name represents the address of the first subarray (i.e) board[0]

This is only true if `board` is used outside of these contexts

- As operand of the `&` operator
- As operand of `sizeof`

When any of that applies, expression `board` represents the array and keeps having the type of the array (`char[3][3]`). Applying the `&` operator to it results in getting the address of the array, which of course equals the address of its first element, merely having a different type (`char(*)[3][3]` instead of `char(*)[3]`). The same that is true about the array `board` is true about its first sub array `board[0]`.

When you use it outside of those contexts, you get the address of the first element (subarray in your case). That address is not an object but just a value. Value have no address, but objects have. Trying to apply `&` on it would fail. For example

```
// error: trying to apply '&' on something that has no address
&(1 ? board : board)
```

Note that anything said above applies to C; not necessarily to C++.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response and i partially understand. Can u provide a simple sample program explaining your comment. I would be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: @intex your question *is* the simple example program i would provide.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this will print the same address.
Think about 2D arrays like this for a minute,

> int **ptr;

The address `*ptr` does equal `&(**ptr)`.

Because basically, that's what your code is doing.

and remember that in memory, 2D arrays will be mapped linearly.

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case that you know an object-oriented language such as Java or Python, and now you are learning the C language. The difference between Java and C when thinking about `char board[3][3]` is that in C the `board` variable is represented in memory as 9 characters at adjacent memory addresses. Like so:

```
board: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

In C, `&board` yields the same memory address as `&board[0]` and `&board[0][0]`.

In contrast to this, in Java the variable would be declared as `char[][] board` and its memory representation would conceptually look like this:

```
board: ptr(A) ptr(B) ptr(C)
A:     1 2 3
B:     4 5 6
C:     7 8 9
```

where `ptr(x)` points to memory address of `x`. So, in Java, `board` points to a different memory address than `board[0]`.

---

> You say In C, &board yields the same memory address as &board[0] and &board[0][0]. But i am able to access the first element only via board[0][0] (or) *board[0] (or) **board. Why is it so??

Although the expressions `&board` and `&board[0]` and `&board[0][0]` yield the same address, the type system of the C language is preventing you from accessing the `char` value. In a C compiler, the types are (conceptually):

```
board:       type char[3][3]
board[0]:    type char[3]
board[0][0]: type char
```

Assuming a variable of type `char`, we can write:

```
char c;
c = board[0][0];
```

but cannot write:

```
char c;
c = board;    // Error
c = board[0]; // Error
```

because the type on the left side is incompatible with the type on the right side of the assignment.

If you are sure that an address points to a `char`, you can use a type cast:

```
char c;
c = *(char*)board;    // Works OK
c = *(char*)board[0]; // Works OK
```

The downside is that such type casts may lead to coding bugs.

Comment: You say In C, &board yields the same memory address as &board[0] and &board[0][0]. But i am able to access the first element only via board[0][0] (or) *board[0] (or) **board. Why is it so??