# Pointers with multi dimensional arrays in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, printf, conversion-specifier

```
int array[2][3] = {{2,3,6},{4,5,8}};

printf("%d\n",*array);
```

What will be the output of this and please explain how?

Regards,

Winston

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two dimensional arrays and pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669773/two-dimensional-arrays-and-pointers)

Comment: `"%d"` and `*array` are incompatible. The first expects a value of type `int`, the latter has type `int[3]` ==> **Undefined Behaviour!**

Comment: Any chance this is a homework or exam question?

Comment: "What will be the output of this" What prevents you from running it and see for yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Educate yourself on multidimensional arrays.

Array `array` is a 2D array:

```
int array[2][3] = {{2,3,6},{4,5,8}};
```

`*array` is the first element of array `array` because

```
*array -> * (array + 0) -> array[0]
```

The first element of array `array` is `array[0]`, which is `{2,3,6}`. The type of `array[0]` is `int [3]`.
When you access an array, it is converted to a pointer to first element (there are few *exceptions* to this rule).

So, in this statement

```
printf("%d\n",*array);
```

`*array` will be converted to type `int *`. The format specifier `%d` expect the argument of type `int` but you are passing argument of type `int *`. The compiler must be throwing warning message for this. Moreover, wrong format specifier lead to undefined behaviour.

If you want to print a pointer, use `%p` format specifier. Remember, format specifier `%p` expect that the argument shall be a pointer to `void`, so you should type cast pointer argument to `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

This call of printf

```
printf("%d\n",*array);
```

invokes undefined behavior because there is used incorrect conversion specifier `%d` with a pointer expression.

If you will write instead

```
printf("%p\n", ( void * )*array);
```

then there will be outputted the address of the extent of memory occupied by the array that is the address of the first element of the array.

That is the expression `*array` has the type `int'[3]`. Used as an argument in the call of `printf` it is implicitly converted to pointer to the first element of the type `int *`. It is the same as to write

```
printf("%p\n", ( void * )&array[0][0]);
```